# Find a smallest number which has exactly N divisors

Tags: algorithm, math

Let's say we have a number of divisors N. And I want to find a `minimum number` that has N divisors.

My algorithm

- I found prime numbers(pm = [2,3,5,7,..])
- I have found N's prime factors(N=12, p=[2,2,3], reversed p rp = [3, 2, 2])
- number *= `pm[i]^(rp[i]-1)`, i = 1...length of prime factors

For the N=12, answer is `60 = 2^(3-1) * 3^(2-1) * 5^(2-1)`

But for the number 243 my algorithm gives wrong answer (5336100 - but it is not minimum number that has 243 divisors). Expected number is `2822400`.

Where is my fault? Any literature?

Comment: @SalvadorDali, it would be cool if you could give me articles, literature about this task. I mean theory.

Comment: Doesn't this also fail for N = 3? Your method appears to give 8, but isn't 6 the right answer?

Comment: @HemanGandhi my method gives 4 for N = 3. 2^(3-1) = 4. And 4 is right answer.

Answer (score 7):

Let's start with the [OEIS sequence](https://oeis.org/A005179). Now any number can be expressed as product of prime powers.

[image]

[How many divisors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) will it have? You can prove using combinatorics that it will have:

[image]

So you have to solve the equation where the expression above is equal to the number of divisions that you have. I will not write a code here, but notice that because you are looking for integer solutions, you can factor out your number of divisors.

When you will find your `m_i`, you can get your smallest number by sorting `m_i` and assigning biggest `m_i` to smallest prime. So if your `m1 = 2`, `m2 = 5`, `m3 = 2`, the number will be `2^5 * 3^2 * 5^2`.

Comment: This answer is not very helpful. You merely re-describe the techniques which OP already has in his question, and, as he's saying, are not always giving the correct answer. The problem is that the solution for `m_i` is not unique. See @user3386109 answer for further analysis.

Comment: @kfx I will make it a little bit more helpful a little bit later. Sorry that it was not helpful for you.

Answer (score 4):

Building upon SalvadorDali's answer:

Given that N is the product of (m<sub>i</sub> + 1), you have attempted to find m<sub>i</sub> by computing the prime factorization of N, and then subtracting 1 from each factor.

That doesn't necessarily give the minimum answer, as shown by your example with N=243. The prime factorization of 243 is

```
243 = 3*3*3*3*3
```

so your method suggests that the minimum should be

```
2^2 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^2 * 11^2 = 5336100
```

However, the alternative composite factorization of 243 is

```
243 = 9*3*3*3
```

which suggests that the minimum should be

```
2^8 * 3^2 * 5^2 * 7^2 = 2822400
```

The composite factorization works better because 2^6 is less than 11^2. So in general, your method is only a starting point. After computing your answer, you need to fold the largest primes into the smallest primes to improve the answer.